# Problem using Laravel when I add a record

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

Great to know you!
I have a problem when I use Laravel to make book bus tickets online system :((. I import *.sql by phpMyadmin so I don't create file migrate.

[This is lichtrinh table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BR81.png)

Everything is well (1st record and 2nd record my application working well) but until I add 3rd record to table, ajax() alert ('Not submit') Althought I just add new record

My file js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btn-submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $username = $('#username').val();
    $pass = $('#pass').val();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/login",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            username: $username,
            pass: $pass
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == '') {
                window.location = "/ve/banve"
            } else {
                $('.toast-container').empty();
                $('.toast-container').append(data);
                $('.toast').each(function (indexInArray,
                    valueOfElement) {
                    var toast2 = new bootstrap.Toast($(this));
                    toast2.show();
                });

            }

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Not submit")
        },

    });
});
```

});

My controller

```
public function findLichTrinh(Request $request)
{
    $lichtrinhs = LichTrinh::where('id_tuyen', $request->id_tuyen)->where('ngaydi', $request->ngaydi)->get();
    $output = "";
    if (!empty($lichtrinhs)) {
        foreach ($lichtrinhs as $lichtrinh) {
            $output .= '<div class="main-item-roundbus m-2 able-cursor">
                            <div class="main-item-title d-inline-flex justify-content-around align-items-center">
                                <span class="text-white">' . $lichtrinh->giodi . '</span>
                                <span class="text-white border border-3 p-1" style="border-radius: 5px;">' . $lichtrinh->xes->bienso . '</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="px-2">
                                <span style="font-size: 17px;" class="fw-bold text-danger text-center">' . $lichtrinh->tuyens->name_tuyen . '</span>
                                <br>
                                <span style="font-size: 17px;">Ghế trống: 10</span><br>
                                <span style="font-size: 17px;">Gía: 100 000 VNĐ</span><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
        }
    } else {
        $output = '<h1>Not Found</h1>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

My route

```
Route::get('/ve/banve/lichtrinh', 'App\Http\Controllers\VeController@findLichTrinh');
```

Thank you very much! Please help me. I'm so sorry, I know my English is not well

Comment: Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: window.location = "/ve/banve" in your javascript but your route is /ve/banve/lichtrinh

Comment: Thank you very much I fixed it, the reason that when I determined One-hasMany relation in Laravel. Love you from VietNam